# How to retrieve the user claims in a Blazor server side app after the user has logged in?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server application and a **AD B2C** authentication. I have configured the Azure and the application is working fine. I can also see the claims with the following code.

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <table style="border: 1px solid black;">
            <tr style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 2px;">
                <th style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 2px;">Claim Type</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 2px;">Value</th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in context.User.Claims)
            {
                <tr style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 2px;">
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 2px;">@item.Type</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 2px;">@item.Value</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

I want to access the **user claims** in a C# class (not in a razor file) and save in a database. How can I achieve that? Are the claims stored in a global object like **HttpContext** from where I can retrieve those?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of AuthenticationStateProvider and from GetAuthenticationStateAsync method you can get user claims.
A sample would be something like this

```
public class Temp
{
    private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider _auth;

    public Temp(AuthenticationStateProvider auth)
    {
        _auth = auth;
    }

    public async Task GetClaims()
    {
        var authState = await _auth.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var userClaims = authState.User.Claims;
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the user to a Group called **Admin**. Where should I look to this group name?

Comment: Are you looking for existing roles?

Comment: If this is what you want you can inject RoleManager<IdentityRole> and then you can have access to Roles

Comment: I don' think **AD B2C** has roles. We can only create groups in *AD* for the users in **B2C** and assign to the same users. So I'm looking for getting the **Group** name.