# Retrieve logged in username in Okta in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, okta

I simply want to retrieve the logged in username in my .net core blazor app, but I have found nothing showing how to do this.

I have not been able to try anything because I have not been able to find anything about this. My program.cs handles the login:

```
using Blazored.SessionStorage;
using Gray_Audit_Workflow.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

builder.Services.AddMvc();

builder.Services.AddBlazoredSessionStorage();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(authOptions => {
    authOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    authOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    authOptions.DefaultSignOutScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    authOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddOpenIdConnect(oidcOptions => {
    oidcOptions.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Okta:ClientId"];
    oidcOptions.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Okta:ClientSecret"];
    oidcOptions.CallbackPath = "/authorization-code/callback";
    oidcOptions.Authority = builder.Configuration["Okta:Issuer"];
    oidcOptions.ResponseType = "code";
    oidcOptions.SaveTokens = true;
    oidcOptions.Scope.Add("openid");
    oidcOptions.Scope.Add("profile");
    oidcOptions.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
    oidcOptions.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
}).AddCookie();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) {
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

app.Run();
```

I can't imagine this is hard to do. But, I have not been able to find anything at all about this.

Comment: Do you know how to access a user's claims from an authorized region/page? It might be saved there already.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't. I'm figuring this out on the fly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66278600/how-to-retrieve-the-user-claims-in-a-blazor-server-side-app-after-the-user-has-l

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know how that solution applies to my situation. I know my problem requires something to do with claims, but I don't understand how that link applies, nor does it give me any idea on how to implement it. I'm new to Okta, so please forgive my ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

I used a combination of the above answer from gunr2171 which linked to another answer about user claims, as well as the okta blazor example repository: https://github.com/okta/samples-blazor

I used razor markup to find which information was being returned from the access token:

```
 @foreach (var claim in context.User.Claims)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@claim.Type</td>
                        <td>@claim.Value</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
```

If you want to show the name of the user, use this:

```
 <p>Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name</p>
```

If you want to retrieve a value from the claim in the code block, you must inject an instance of the AuthenticationStateProvider at the top of your razor page:

```
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider
```

Then in the code block you can do something like this:

```
@code {

    public string oktaId { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = authState.User;

        oktaId = user.Claims.First().Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

For me, I needed the okta user id, which happened to be the first value in the claims list. I noticed that the okta login name was in that list when I looped through the claim types in my html. I hope this helps! I am new to this as well and just spent the better part of 2 weeks trying to figure this out.